# Socket connection established but server to client message could not be emitted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io for my Node app. The socket connection within the app has been established but data does not get emitted from server to client.
Client & server are on different port (3000 & 8080)

**Client Side: **

client side connection:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
    vary: origin,
    })
```

```
const sendMessage =()=>{
        socket.emit('SENDMSG',{message: 'hello'})
        joinRoom()
    }


    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on("receive_msg", (data)=>{
            new Audio(order).play()
            console.log('data', data.ListOfOrders)
            setTableItems(data.ListOfOrders)
        });
    }, [socket])

    const joinRoom = ()=>{
        socket.emit('join_room', email)
    }
```

**Server Side JS:**

```
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)

const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors:{
        origin: `http://localhost:3000`,
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
        credentials: true,
        transports: ['websocket','polling'],
    },
    allowEIO3: true
});
```

// Runs when Client connects

```
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    socket.on('join_room', (data)=>{
        console.log(data).  <----------------This gets printed meaning connection established.
        socket.join(data)
    })
})
```

```
app.post('/placeorder', async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const { ordersList, spiceLevel, name, id } = req.body
        const searchRestaurant = await Restaurants.findOne({shopName: name}).populate('orders');
        for (let order of ordersList){
            let orderEntry = new Orders({
                qty: order.qty,
                food: order.itemName,
                tableNo: id,
                spiceLevel: spiceLevel, 
                discount: order.discount,
                price: order.price,
                remarks: order.remarks
            })
            await orderEntry.save()
            searchRestaurant.orders.push(orderEntry._id)
            await searchRestaurant.save();
        }
        const ListOfOrders = searchRestaurant.orders
        **io.to(searchRestaurant.email).emit('receive_msg', {ListOfOrders})** -> Data not emitted
        return res.status(200).send('Order has been placed')
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).send('Something went wrong. Please go back or refresh your browser.');
    }
})
```

Can anyone help me fix this ? Let me know if you need more details.
My receiver side socket is in useEffect hook if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the event is emitted  all connected clients  you must move the io.to    (searchRestaurant.email).emit('receive_msg', {ListOfOrders}) line inside  socket.on('join_room', ...) callback on the server-side.
This will ensure that the event is emitted to all clients that are in the same room

your server-side updated code

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join_room', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    socket.join(data);
  });
});

app.post('/placeorder', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { ordersList, spiceLevel, name, id } = req.body;
    const searchRestaurant = await Restaurants.findOne({ shopName: name }).populate('orders');
    for (let order of ordersList) {
      let orderEntry = new Orders({
        qty: order.qty,
        food: order.itemName,
        tableNo: id,
        spiceLevel: spiceLevel,
        discount: order.discount,
        price: order.price,
        remarks: order.remarks
      });
      await orderEntry.save();
      searchRestaurant.orders.push(orderEntry._id);
      await searchRestaurant.save();
    }
    const ListOfOrders = searchRestaurant.orders;
    io.to(searchRestaurant.email).emit('receive_msg', { ListOfOrders }); 
    return res.status(200).send('your message');
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send('your message.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this a updated server-side code ? I could not see any change in code.